# Angular Bootstrap : how to layout two widgets side-by-side in a modal window

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to place two Kendo UI widgets side-by-side within an Angular-UI modal window.

My problem is that they are getting place one below the other as in the embedded screen shot.

Note the Dimensions List on top (`<li ng-repeat`), and the Dimension Grid on the bottom. I'd like these to be side-by-side :

[image: modal window with two UI widgets]

Here's the HTML template, which is part of the Angular Bootstrap modal :

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>User Dimensions</legend>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="radios-0">Choose One</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="radio">
            <label for="radios-0">
                <input name="radios" id="radio1" value="1"  type="radio">
                Defined Portfolios
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label for="radios-1">
                <input name="radios" id="radio2" value="2" checked="checked" type="radio">
                Specify Dimensions
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="radios-0">Dimensions</label>

    <!-- *** KENDO SORTABLE *** -->
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="dim-list" kendo-sortable k-placeholder="settings.placeholder" k-hint="settings.hint">
            <li ng-repeat="dim in settings.dimenDS">{{dim.name}}</li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <!-- *** KENDO GRID *** -->
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <span id="userDimenGrid" kendo-grid="settings.userDimenGrid" 
                        k-data-source="settings.userDimenGridDS"
                        k-options="settings.userDimenGridOptions" 
                        k-rebind="settings.userDimenGridOptions" />
    </div>
</div>       

</fieldset>
</form>

<style scoped>    

   .dim-list li{
    list-style-type:none;
    background-color:silver; 
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    width: 180px;
    margin: 5px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;          
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor:move;
 }
li.hint {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #52aef7;
    color: #fff;
}

li.hint:last-child {
    border-radius: 4px;
}

li.hint span {
    color: #fff;
}

li.placeholder {
    background-color: #dceffd;
    color: #52aef7;
    text-align: right;
}
</style>
```

I would like this to be side by side, but having much trouble formatting it as such within this `<form>` .

Answer (score 0):

final solution :

I ended up spending more time working with bootstrap classes `row` and/or `row-fluid`, as well as `col-lg-4`.

It turns out the standard `"form-group"` class won't exactly work with what I want to do. Of course, since it's not exactly a form. Rather I'm placing Kendo UI widgets side by side.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>User Dimensions</legend>

 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="radios-0">Choose One</label>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="radio">
            <label for="radios-0">
                <input name="radios" id="radio1" value="1"  type="radio">
                Defined Portfolios
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <label for="radios-1">
                <input name="radios" id="radio2" value="2" checked="checked" type="radio">
                Specify Dimensions
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-lg-3">                

            <ul class="dim-list" kendo-sortable k-hint="settings.hint" k-move="settings.move" k-end="settings.end" k-placeholder="settings.placeholder">
                <li ng-repeat="dim in settings.dimenDS">{{dim.name}}</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <span id="userDimenGrid" kendo-grid="settings.userDimenGrid" 
                            k-data-source="settings.userDimenGridDS"
                            k-options="settings.userDimenGridOptions" 
                            k-rebind="settings.userDimenGridOptions" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 </fieldset>
</form>
<style scoped>    
   .dim-list li{
    list-style-type:none;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:silver; 
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    width: 180px;
    margin: 5px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;          
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor:move;
}
li.hint {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #52aef7;
    color: #fff;
}

li.hint:last-child {
    border-radius: 4px;
}

li.hint span {
    color: #fff;
}

li.placeholder {
    background-color: #dceffd;
    color: #52aef7;
    text-align: right;
}
```